# Java 9 - how to recompile .jar library with module-info

Tags: java-9, java-module, jlink, module-info, jdeps

I read that to add .jar libraries as dependency in java9 modules, we just need to include them in --module-path and they will be converted to 'Atomatic Modules'

However when I try to use jLink, I still got the error:
Error: module-info.class not found for dd.plist module

I realized that we can generate module-info.java with jdeps, my question is how I can recompile the .jar library with this module-info.java?

Comment: Also, would be good to know if the question might be solved in another way. What command from `jlink` are you using?

Comment: the command im Using is -> jlink --module-path 'path to modules with separators' --add-modules larrybot --launcher laucnherClass --output dist --strip-debug --compress 2 --no-header-files --no-man-pages